# UK payment to US bank: put ABA inside BIC/SWIFT box

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, international-transfer

Regarding a UK-to-USA payment made in USD:

I've made a payment and confused the field for the BIC/SWIFT number with the destination bank ABA number, the funds left earlier on today from my bank, what happens from here? Will the ABA number be enough for this money to be wired correctly?

First time making international payments and tearing my hair out! Terminology differences on their payment form: they have routing ABA, while on my bank's payment page it said beneficiary routing number. (BIC).

I'm sure this all makes sense, and I'm just been a little stupid (likely).

Edit: Payment worked! Thanks to all posters below who were correct it routed correctly and within 24 hours.

Comment: You're /probably/ OK. So long as the obvious fields were on the form, it's either going to get to the right place or come back. So don't worry, and apologise to the people you're paying if there's a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the ABA number be enough for this money to wire correctly?

On international payment to US, you can either quote [SWIFT BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362) or ABA. [ABA also called routing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number) is similar to Sort Code [SC] for UK. i.e. it identifies a particular Bank/branch in US.

So the payment will go through correctly if either use the BIC or ABA.